# open and read a type='file' on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

I have this code :

```
<form onSubmit="return checkFile();" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST' action="index.php?status=import" >
    <input name="tracklistFile" type="file" value="CHOOSE" />   
    <input type="submit" name="send" />
</form>
```

and I'd like, before submit it to the server, call that function `checkFile()`, that must open this file, read it and do some check operations.

1. Can I do it on Javascript?
2. Is it better (cause cross-browsers) use a framework? (jQuery?)

Thanks

P.S. Of course I'll do the same check operations of the file on server side, but I'd like to test it also client-side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to access/open any files using javascript. The browser security system will not allow this.

It is same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: neither for just read the file?

Comment: yes.. the browser's sandbox will not allow access to any local resources in the system.

Comment: Thanks man! It's a bit bad this, but ok :)